# mysql showing error as FUNCTION xxxxx.GETKeyList does not exist

Tags: php, mysql

We have an application and which is running with php and mysql. We are using  very little so after the use, we have stopped all its resources.

In the last when we started the application and when we login, searching some strings showing error as given below

FUNCTION xxxxx.GETKeyList does not exist

How we can resolve this issue? Is this is an error related to procedure or function in the missing database?

how I can find more details about this error? If it's a function  I have checked the show function status; and i have got all the details, but I can't find anything related to GETKeyList. Is someone faced this issue before?

Comment: It's clear, the developper who made the database has create a function or procedure in MySQL with the name GETKeyList. You have to create this function too, but withou backup or information of what do this function you faced too a big problem.

Comment: I took the backup before terminating the database, but when I restore it the function is not showing over there.  Is there any other way to restore this procedure or functions

Comment: Did you take routines in your backup ? Sometimes it was not auto include in the mysqldump command

Comment: Take a look here for more information : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_routines